# Package Deployer - Creating a Package that skips import step if data already exists

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've created a package for use with the package deployer tool ([MSDN article here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688182.aspx)). 
However, I'd like to make it idempotent so that I can run it multiple times with the same result. Is it possible to tell the package to not run the data import if the data already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Package Deployer Tool already can detect whether a solution installation and data migrations have already been performed and skips over them. There's no need to code this in the package itself.